Evil cursor goes back up to previous line in REPL
In jupeter-repl-mode, when the cursor is on an empty line, right next to the prompt, exiting Evil insert state moves the cursor back to the previous line. I solved this like this:
;;; Fix cursor going up a line when exiting the insert mode at the prompt.
(defun a2/evil-exit-insert-state-leave-cursor-here ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (evil-normal-state)
  (evil-next-line))

I wonder whether other people have encountered this problem. This only works because if the cursor stays put, there is no next line to go to.
Setting evil-move-cursor-back to nil doesn't help.
I am using Doom Emacs. I had a similar problem before with IPython REPL as well, I think.
